# Trying to get Python example to work from ArcGIS website, getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, error-handling, anaconda, arcgis

I am trying to get an example from ArcGIS's tutorials to work but am getting the following error:  "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".  I read on the ArcGIS website that I need to use Anaconda for this to work so I am using Spyder version 3.9 (also a requirement) according to their website.  Code is below and Error below that.  I wondered if everyone else is getting the same error or not.

I copied the example from the following URL:  https://developers.arcgis.com/python/samples/detecting-swimming-pools-using-satellite-image-and-deep-learning/

Python Code:

````
```
######################################################################################
# https://developers.arcgis.com/python/samples/detecting-swimming-pools-using-satellite-image-and-deep-learning/
######################################################################################
## Part 1 - export training data for deep learning
## Import ArcGIS API for Python and get connected to your GIS
import arcgis
import sys
from arcgis import GIS, learn
from arcgis.raster import analytics
from arcgis.raster.functions import extract_band, apply, clip
from arcgis.raster.analytics import list_datastore_content
from arcgis.learn import SingleShotDetector, prepare_data, Model, list_models, detect_objects 
arcgis.env.verbose = True
from arcgis.geocoding import geocode

gis = GIS('https://pythonapi.playground.esri.com/portal', 'arcgis_python', 'amazing_arcgis_123')

## Prepare data that will be used for training data export
pool_bb = gis.content.get('3443553a9e8443eeb570ef1b973e44a8')
pool_bb


pool_bb_layer = pool_bb.layers[0]    #<-- Error happens on this line
pool_bb_layer.url

m = gis.map("Prospect Park, Redlands, CA")
m

m.basemap = 'gray'


# Now let's retrieve the NAIP image layer.
naip_item = gis.content.get('2f8f066d526e48afa9a942c675926785')
naip_item
```
````

```
    **Error Message:**
    <html>
    <head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      Cell In[10], line 18
        **pool_bb_layer = pool_bb.layers[0]**
    
    ***TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable***
```

I haven't been able to get any of their examples to work for the same reason.  What do I need to do here to make the example work?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can point you in the right direction, print(pool_bb) to see what you get and:
https://python-forum.io/thread-17825.html

Reference "In general, the error means that you attempted to index an object that doesn't have that functionality."

Comment: Thanks, I gathered that was the issue.  I am looking for a solution to the issue.  Maybe their data connection isn't good so I wondered if anyone can try it on their machine and tell me if they are getting the same thing?

Comment: You are welcome. But what did print(pool_bb) give you?

Comment: ```## Prepare data that will be used for training data export
pool_bb = gis.content.get('3443553a9e8443eeb570ef1b973e44a8')
pool_bb
Out[16]: <Item title:"SwimmingPoolLabels" type:Feature Layer Collection owner:api_data_owner>```